Standard error of mean with varying replicates for batches
I have three batches of simulations and I calculate a specific property from these (not important for the question). I want to calculate combined SEM for these three batches
Batch  | #samples | average | standard deviation | standard error
B1     |     n1   |     x1  |          sd1       |          se1
B2     |     n2   |     x2  |          sd2       |          se2
B3     |     n3   |     x3  |          sd3       |          se3
My approach is as follows
SE_combined = $\sqrt{\frac{(n1-1)se1^2 + (n2-1)se2^2 + (n3-1)se3^2}{n1+n2+n3-3}}$
Is this correct approach? Also, I need some paper/book reference for citation. Any help would be really helpful!

What was the data generated in batches? And can you explain how sd1 and se1 are computed?

@dipetkov B1 has a scalar parameter output from a simulation. For example, assume n1 is 4 (simulations) then B1 would be something like [0.98, 0.95, 0.8, 0.91]. These are simulation outputs. Finally, x1 and sd1 are average and std deviation of these outputs. se1 would be sd1/sqrt(4) parameters.

Thanks. It still not clear to me why there are batches and why you don't have the individual data points. The reason I'm asking is that in some situations it's not reasonable to assume there are no batch effects.

@dipetkov I was not sure about #simulations needed for results to be statistically significant. So, we just picked n1, n2, n3 as 50, 100 and 150. Essentially, we have a non-deterministic algorithm that is sensitive to initialization so we initialize with a random guess (iteration are large enough for convergence) to average out the resulting output parameter. All I need is some reference that I can cite for computing SE for this case!

Okay, no batch effects then. Your formula is similar to the formula for the pooled variance $s_p^2$ except for the unnecessary division by sqrt(4) = 2. I guess you want to estimate the overall mean and then a standard error for that overall mean ignoring the grouping by batches? Then you need something different from $s_p^2$ because every component $s_i^2$ in the pooled variance is computed wrt the batch mean $\bar{y}_i$, not the overall mean.

I am still bit confused about going from pooled variance to SE. I do need batch mean as every batch has different #samples.  Once I get $s_p^2$, how do I get overall SE for all three batches? Also more importantly, I need citation source!

Wikipedia? I still think you haven't described precisely what you want to compute: the pooled variance or the sample variance of the 3 batches concatenated into one sample. I suggest you edit your question with an example. Say, use three batches of size 3, 4, 5. Pick 12 numbers at random and work out both the entries in the table as well as the SE you want to compute.
